# Is it possible manage a transaction between two class mediator?

Tags: wso2

I have to write a sequence where I have to call 2 class mediator.
Each class mediator must call a session EJB which call an entity EJB to create a record.
Is it possible to manage the 2 calls inside a transaction ?
Cheers.

```
        warxsg
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the transaction form your code in the class mediators. ESB has no knowledge on the transaction happening, and hence cannot do anything at the infrastructure level.